How can I calculate derivative of eigenstates numerically?
I want to calculate $\langle n | \partial_{k_x} n \rangle$ where $| n \rangle \equiv | u_{n,\mathbf{k}} \rangle $ is the $n$-th Bloch eigenstate of a $6\times6$ Hamiltonian $H\equiv H(\mathbf{k})$. The wave vector $\mathbf{k}$ lies inside the first Brillouin zone (BZ).
Due to the nature of $H$, I can't calculate eigen vectors $| n \rangle $ analytically, so, I have to do it numerically. But the numerical eigenvectors never behave smooth enough to calculate their numerical derivative (see * below).
The other method is to rewrite $\langle n | \partial_{k_x} n \rangle$. I start by Schordinger equation $H|n\rangle=E_n|n\rangle$ and take derivative of both sides and apply $\langle m|$ from left to obtain
$$
\langle m |\partial_{k_x} n\rangle = \frac{(\partial_{k_x}E_n)\langle m | n\rangle - \langle m |(\partial_{k_x}H)|n\rangle}{E_m - E_n +i\eta},
$$
here $E_n\equiv E_{n,\mathbf{k}}$ is $n$-th eigenvalue, and I take $\eta$ a small positive number to avoid singularities. Now, if I put $m=n$, I get
$$
\langle n |\partial_{k_x} n\rangle = \frac{(\partial_{k_x}E_n) - \langle n |(\partial_{k_x}H)|n\rangle}{i\eta}.
$$
Now, the whole quantity is inversely proportional to $\eta$. My question is why? Technically the $\eta$ should be zero. But then the whole term diverges. Does it mean that we can never calculate $\langle n | \partial_{k_x} n \rangle$ numerically? What is physical significance of $\eta$ here?

*: At each k-point I calculate $H$ and solve eigenvalue problem and get six matrices of size 6 by 1 (each matrix is a eigenvector  $| n \rangle $). Now, after calculating eigenvector at $N$ k-points inside BZ, when I perform the numerical derivative, the results does not make sense... because of how the eigenvalue problem is solved by numerical methods (i.e., if $f(\mathbf{k})$ is an eigenvector then $e^{i\phi}f(\mathbf{k})$ is also an eigenvector). So, this method will fail, no matter what.

Edit: What exactly am I trying to calculate?
I want to calculate the second term of eq. 61 of this paper, which is the off-diagonal components of orbital angular momentum operator:
$$
\mathbf{M}_{ln} = \frac{-i(1-\delta_{ln})}{4}(E_l - E_n)\left(\langle l | \partial_{\mathbf{k}} l \rangle + \langle n | \partial_{\mathbf{k}} n \rangle\right)\times \langle l | \partial_{\mathbf{k}} n \rangle.
$$
It will be ultimately used to calculate orbital Berry curvature as
$$
\Omega_\nu^z = -2Im\sum_{\mu}\frac{J_{\nu\mu}^{M}V_{\mu\nu}^y}{(E_\nu - E_\mu)^2}
$$
with $J_{\nu\mu}^{M} = \sum_\alpha ( V_{\nu\alpha}^x M_{\alpha\nu}^z + M_{\nu\alpha}^z V_{\alpha\nu}^x )$. We can easily write $\langle l | \partial_{\mathbf{k}} n \rangle$ as $\frac{\mathbf{V}_{ln}}{E_l-E_n}$ but $\langle n | \partial_{\mathbf{k}} n \rangle$ is the problem. $V$ is the velocity operator.

The derivative is not well-defined. So let me ask the question: Why do you want to calculate it? If you're goal is to get a Berry phase by integrating the derivative, or get a Berry curvature by differentiating the derivative, you can discretize the problem without ever computing a derivative as in chapter 2 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.02295

@JahanClaes I have edited the question to add what I am planning to calculate. It is orbital Berry curvature. I am sure that we can't apply the technique mentioned in this book. Please have a look at it and give your valuable comments. Thank you.

When the parameter-dependent Schrödinger equation
$$
H(k) |n\rangle(k) = E_n(k)|n\rangle(k)\tag{0}
$$
has a solution that depends on the parameter $k$ in a smooth manner, then indeed, differentiating and applying $\langle m|$, you get the following equality
$$
(E_m-E_n)\langle m|(\partial_k|n\rangle) = (\partial_k E_n)\delta_{nm} - \langle m| (\partial_kH)|n\rangle\tag{1}
$$
without the parameter $\eta$. For $m = n$ this equality gives the Hellmann-Feynman theorem
$$
\partial_k E_n = \langle n| (\partial_kH)|n\rangle.
$$
Therefore, it is actually impossible to express the desired value $\langle n|(\partial_k|n\rangle)$ from equality (1). And this is natural, since the vector-valued function $|n\rangle(k)$ is not uniquely defined. Multiplication by a parameter-dependent phase factor yields another vector-valued function $\tilde{|n\rangle}(k) = e^{i\gamma(k)}|n\rangle(k)$ satisfying the same equation (0), which, however, corresponds to a completely different value of $\tilde{\langle n|}(\partial_k\tilde{|n\rangle}) = \langle n|(\partial_k|n\rangle) + i\partial_k\gamma$. So the formulas simply reproduce what you noticed when analyzing the reasons for the failure of the numerical approach.
So there is no divergence in your second formula, when $\eta = 0$ there is uncertainty $0/0$ on the right side. The parameter $\eta$ looks like it was introduced formally and in more regular expressions it should simply disappear without a trace.

Ahan, it makes sense. Thank you.
I have edited the question to add what I am planning to calculate. Please have a look at it. Is there anyway we can calculate $M_{ln}$ quantity?
Thank you.

I can't give you an exact answer, but perhaps I can point you in the right direction. First off, the question of how to construct the k-gradient in the whole BZ is not easy to answer. I assume that you stumbled across the problem to define transition dipole or momentum elements in a solid [1].
As already pointed out, you obtain the eigenvectors at each $k$ independently up to a phase factor $e^{i\gamma(k)}$, but of course associated "physical" quantities are not affected by this gauge-freedom. If you consider the semiconductor Bloch equations (SBEs) you can have a look at this paper [2]. You will see that you are not only able to calculate the gradient for $m=n$ but it is even required to ensure gauge invariance of the equations. Furthermore, again in the context of SBEs you might use them to construct a smooth phase functions which is also periodic at the boundaries of the BZ [3].
However, this is not always possible, in which case the material is called non-trivial [4]. A bigger problem is degeneracy which is circumvented by projecting the eigenvectors onto a smooth set of eigenvectors and is called wannierization [5]. A very neat summary of all the aforementioned problems and approaches can be found here [6].
Conclusion
If you just started to experiment with calculating the k-gradient in a solid I recommend implementing the Haldane model presented in [4] both analytically and numerically by following the approach in [3].


Relation between the interband dipole and momentum matrix elements in semiconductors
Phase invariance of the semiconductor Bloch equations
Structure gauges and laser gauges for the semiconductor Bloch equations in high-order harmonic generation in solids
Circular dichroism in higher-order harmonic generation: Heralding topological phases and transitions in Chern insulators
Maximally localized Wannier functions: Theory and applications
Introduction to theory of high-harmonic generation in solids: tutorial


Wow. This is so exciting to learn. In [3] they mention three methods to calculate Berry connection numerically (in Table 1 with eq. 8). (1) Discrete, (2) Discrete with parallel transport (PT) gauge, and (3) Discrete with twisted parallel transport (TPT) gauge .
So to be clear, I can use Method#1 (the one with natural log) to calculate Berry connection without doing anything special with my numerically calculated $|n\rangle$? (Currently, I don't want to impose TP/TPT.)
By the way, I want to invite you to have a collaboration on this project... It is a small project. I am a PhD student.
